# Pls help: Integral definition from textbook

Tags: calculus, integration

I am supposed to learn this explanation of integrals. But don't really get it.

[image]

> This area underneath the staircase in Figure 1.7 is composed of rectangles. The base of every rectangle is 1. The heights of the rectangles are the v's. So the areas also equal the v's and the total area is the sum of the v's. This area is f_last-f_first.
> Even more is true. We could start at any time and end at any later time-not necessarily at the special times t=0,1,2,3,4. Suppose we stop at t=3.5. Only half of the last rectangular (under v=7) will be counted. The total area is 1+3+5+1/2(7)=12.5. This still agrees with f_last-f_first=12.5-0. At this new ending time t=3.5, we are only halfway up the last step in the f-graph. Halfway between 9 and 16 is 12.5

I understand why this works for whole numbers as the rectangulars for each point is 1*v, but I don't understand why this works for t=3.5, ;when we look at 3.5 the rectangular is 0.5*v and not v so i can't just add them up. Why does it work at 3.5?

Comment: I understand integrals, and still find the text you linked very difficult to understand.  Here is an explanation of integration that imo is better written: https://sam.nitk.ac.in/courses/MA110/Introduction%20to%20Integration.pdf (the whole thing is very long, but you only need up to slide 15 for this particular topic)

Comment: What does "f_last-f_first" mean?

Comment: the difference in the x-values